# How to correctly handle events using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I was wondering- where is the correct place to handle, for example ajax requests in Cordova app. I'm completely new with Cordova (started few days ago), so I just implemented that by simply puting ajax code in to 'ajaxHandler.js' file.
and then at the app's index.html I load it the end of the body:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxHandler.js"></script>
```

example of how I handle reguests:
let say we have a button with id '#SendRequest', then in 'ajaxHandler.js' I'd do:

```
$('#sendRequest').on('click', function(){

var json_data = {...someData...};
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/some_url',
  data: json_data,
    success: function(dataR){

      processData(dataR);

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

      console.log("Status: " + textStatus); console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);

    },
    timeout: 5000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
  });
  return false;

});
```

function processData(); that handles the data returned by the server is also defined in the same file.

However, I've tried reading some tutorials and people seem to integrate all apps functionality into auto-generated 'index.js'

for example I'd do:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
onDeviceReady: function() {

    console.log(" device ready!");

    $("#sendRequest").click(sendAjaxRequest);


  }
};
//define variables and functions here

function sendAjaxRequest{..function..};

//then call app.initialize

app.initialize();
```

The way I've done it seem to work just fine and I like my way because I can organise code into different files. For example, I have a lot of buttons in my app to open menus, switch pages, etc. I handle those 'clicks' in 'interface.js', I handle requests, as mentioned before in 'ajaxHandler.js', and so on. Then I just laod the files at the end of body in index.html. This way the code is organised and pleasure to work with.

Should I also cram all functionality of the app in 'index.js', If so, why? Cordova's documentation does not explicitly state the 'correct' way to do things.

Comment: There is no correct way. Just guidelines by other so called developers.

Comment: why would you trigger a click to make an ajax request?

Comment: Nirus, are you talking about the '$("#sendRequest").click(sendAjaxRequest);' ? Im handling the click not triggering the event. When you pass some function, eg handler() to .click() its the same as .on('click',handler()) . In my case I'm sending some json to the server when a button is taped.